# Does aiohttp process/encode form data differently than requests does?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

## Overview

I've written a script that goes to a page, scrapes the form inputs, and then posts back to the same page (just like a user would do; need to do this to get hidden inputs/tokens/etc.).

My script uses `requests.Session` currently and I am trying to migrate to async and use `aiohttp.ClientSession` instead.

The requests version of this login function works, but the aiohttp version sends but returns an invalid login response.

Does aiohttp do something special to the data dictionary that I pass to `s.post(...)`? I saw that aiohttp is [slightly opinionated when it comes to cookies](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#cookie-quoting-routine) whereas requests is not. Does that extend to form data encoding as well?

## Relevant Code Snippets

requests version

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = '...'

def login(s: requests.Session, username: str, password: str) -> requests.Response:
    response = s.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    inputs = soup.select('form input')
    data = {
        el['name']: el['value']
        for el in inputs
        if el.get('name') and el.get('value')
    }
    data.update({
        'Username': username,
        'Password': password
    })
    return s.post(URL, data=data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.session() as s:
        response = login(s, <username>, <password>)
```

aiohttp version

```py
import asyncio

import aiohttp
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = '...'

async def login(s: aiohttp.ClientSession, username: str, password: str) -> aiohttp.ClientResponse:
    async with s.get(URL) as response:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(await response.text(), 'html.parser')

    inputs = soup.select('form input')
    data = {
        el['name']: el['value']
        for el in inputs
        if el.get('name') and el.get('value')
    }
    data.update({
        'Username': username,
        'Password': password,
    })

    return await s.post(URL, data=data)

async def main():
    jar = aiohttp.CookieJar(quote_cookie=False)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(cookie_jar=jar) as s:
        response = await login(s, <username>, <password>)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

## Things I've Tried

I've printed out the `data` variable before it was sent in both cases and they are identical (except for random tokens, etc. that the page generated), I've tried changing the content-type headers, I've spun up a quick Flask server to which I've sent both of these requests and the `request.data` looks identical.

## Versions

Ran on Ubuntu 20

Python: 3.8.5

Pip freeze output

```
aiodns==2.0.0
aiohttp==3.7.3
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==20.3.0
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
brotlipy==0.7.0
cchardet==2.1.7
certifi==2020.12.5
cffi==1.14.4
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
idna==2.10
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
multidict==5.1.0
numpy==1.19.5
pandas==1.2.0
pycares==3.1.1
pycparser==2.20
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-dotenv==0.15.0
pytz==2020.5
requests==2.25.1
six==1.15.0
soupsieve==2.1
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
ua-parser==0.10.0
urllib3==1.26.2
Werkzeug==1.0.1
yarl==1.6.3
```

## Main Question

Does aiohttp process/encode form data differently than requests does? If not, what are some reason that the aiohttp request would fail?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set allow_redirects=False and do it manually.

```
async def login(s: aiohttp.ClientSession, username: str, password: str) -> aiohttp.ClientResponse:
    async with s.get(URL) as response:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(await response.text(), 'html.parser')

    inputs = soup.select('form input')
    data = {
        el['name']: el['value']
        for el in inputs
        if el.get('name') and el.get('value')
    }
    data.update({
        'Username': username,
        'Password': password,
    })

    resp = await s.post(URL, data=data, allow_redirects=False)
    return await s.get(resp.headers.get('Location'))
```